# Unexpected value change of 2nd Potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer, midi, arduino-duemilanove

[image]I'm trying to connect 2 potentiometer (10k) and pass their value to Hairless Midi software (For Serial to Midi Bridge) the first pot is working fine but the second pot's value keep on changing and when i move around the knob of pot1 the value of pot 2 also changes.

I have tried reading the value twice but no luck....

My code:

```
void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);      
}

void loop()
{
  analogRead(0);
   val = analogRead(0)/8;   // Divide by 8 to get range of 0-127 for midi
   if (val > lastVal+1 or val < lastVal+1 ) 
   {
   MIDImessage(176,1,val);}        
   lastVal = val;

  analogRead(2);
   val2 = analogRead(2)/8;   // Divide by 8 to get range of 0-127 for midi
   if (val2 > lastVal2 + 1 or val2 < lastVal2 + 1 )
   {
   MIDImessage(176,2,val2);}         // 176 = CC command, 2 = Which Control, val = value read from Potentionmeter 2
   lastVal2 = val2;

   //val3 = analogRead(2)/8;   // Divide by 8 to get range of 0-127 for midi
   //if (val3 != lastVal3) 
   //{
   //MIDImessage(176,3,val3);}         // 176 = CC command, 3 = Which Control, val = value read from Potentionmeter 3
   //lastVal3 = val3;

delay(100);
}

void MIDImessage(byte command, byte data1, byte data2) //pass values out through standard Midi Command
{
   Serial.write(command);
   Serial.write(data1);
   Serial.write(data2);
}
```

[image: Connected Second pot to A0 which was earlier for Pot 1 and removed pot 1]

Comment: What happens if you swap the two pot? That shield point to whether it’s a software or hardware problem.

Comment: I have tried swapping the pots,changing the input pin number but still the problem persist...

Comment: What is your circuit? Did you wire the pots in series maybe?

Comment: Give me 5 min i will upload my circuit...

Comment: You should have something like that, right? (http://i.stack.imgur.com/JrLxr.png)

Comment: This is my circuit

Comment: You must have an error in your circuit. It works on my Arduino Nano and 2 pots perfectly. See screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVzLR.png and code https://pastebin.com/Ww7JcBp0 and circuit picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zpN0.jpg

Comment: I have connected the same way as my circuit image and your is also the same right...

Comment: Try to add more debugging. Instead of connecting the serial to a MIDI device, let it print out the raw Pot analog values and the "would be sent" MIDI bytes to your PC.

Comment: One More thing i tried out what i did was I removed the pot one connection from arduino and connected the pot 2 to arduino pin 0 which was earlier used for pot 1. So here the values are changing automatically...adding the circuit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75060/discussion-between-ronaldo-and-maximilian-gerhardt).

Comment: Also posted on the [Arduino Forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=537241.0)

Comment: @tttapa  that's me who had posted on the Arduino forum  i got a lot of help from there but got stuck at this point so posted it here also...

Answer (score 1):

As I was having chat with @Maxmilian Gerhardt he suggested to check the voltage of pot 2 so when I checked I was getting 0 volt So he Suggested me there may be a loose connection or something with the beadboard.

So This was a workaround :

[image]

Thnx for the help @Maxmilian Gerhardt

Comment: Some of those protoboards have power rails split in the middle.